# (flutter) the return type MaterialApp{...} shows error : Type cant be returned from method 'build' as it has return type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp{
      title:'First app',
    home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('app'),
     ),
     body : Center(

        child: Text('Hello'),
   ),
   );
    };
}
}
```

the 3rd line shows the error on '`MaterialApp`'.

**Error description :**

> Type cant be returned from method 'build' as it has return type
>   'Widget'.

Answer (score 4):

Hey there Material App is supposed to be wrapped with ()

Example => https://dartpad.dev/e7432b0d8c215625f3acf8aa8fbedb86